# C strtok and strcpy

Tags: c, parsing, strtok, strcpy

I have a text file, similar to the following:

```
Name1: ID1
Name2: ID2
Name3: ID3
```

I am trying to parse it to get

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
```

stored in a variable.

I wrote the following function:

```
/*
 *  filename    Name of file to read
 *  result      The result will be stored here
 */

void readlist(char* filename, char* result) {
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[2048];
    memset((void *)result, '\0', BUFFER_SIZE);

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)) {
        char *token = NULL;
        token = strtok( buffer, ":" );
        strcat(result, token);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

However when I call it:

```
char result[2048];
readlist("test.txt", result);
printf("%s", result);
```

I'm getting an empty output. It seems that strtok() messes up the data, but I might be wrong.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code (or at least, I created a single program from the snippets of your code) and it worked fine for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void readlist(char* filename, char* result);

int main(void) {
char result[2048];
readlist("test.txt", result);
printf("%s", result);
}

void readlist(char* filename, char* result) {
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[2048];

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)) {
        char *token = NULL;
        token = strtok( buffer, ":" );
        strcat(result, token);
    }


    fclose(fp);
}
```

When I ran it on your input file, I got as output

```
Name1Name2Name3
```

Exactly as expected.

This was using the gcc compiler version 4.2.1 on Mac OS . It suggests your code isn't as far off as you think (whether the compiler initializes the string to 0 before starting is implementation dependent, apparently).  To be safe though, you need to make sure your initial result is all zeros. You could do

```
char result[2048] = {'\0'};
```

This would guarantee all elements are initialized to zero. Another method would be to use

```
static char result[2048];
```

Since any variable declared `static` will be initialized to zero.

Finally, things like

```
result[0] = '\0';
```

would start the string with zero length - and whatever follows doesn't matter. This is probably the cleanest.

Comment: Thank you for checking this out for me. I've spent many hours trying to figure out the problem. Looks like something is wrong with my compiler...

Comment: Thanks for the accept, but I think you are jumping to conclusions about your compiler being "wrong". I think that behavior is "not defined" for things like this. Follow one of the suggestions I made for ensuring that `result` is initialized to something sensible (as was also pointed out by other answers) - don't just blame your compiler!

Comment: Yes, I tried that, however this was not the case. I have a while(1) {} loop later on in the main() function and for some reason it was causing the output getting stuck, even though the output code is before and outside the loop. Thank very much!

Comment: Ah... The infamous  "other bit of code" . This is the reason why it is always recommended that you ask your problems as small, self contained, complete programs that reproduce the problem. Well I am glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 2):

You never initialized result, before the call to `readlist` or after.

just add before the call to `readlist`: `strcpy(result, "");`

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this is not the problem (I tried that).

Comment: i wonder if your problem is that you were reading a file with RETURNS and LINEFEEDS, and the RETURNS were messing your output and making it look as if nothing was matched. I recommend you redirect the output to a file (eg. ./program > save.output) and inspect the output in an editor.

Answer (score 2):

```
char result[2048];
```

Initialize this statement otherwise result will contain garbage values as its an `auto` variable.

So use `char result[2048] = "";` before `readlist()` is called in your `main` function.

Comment: @max Have you checked file is proper and You are able to read the file?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you initialize `result` to an empty string. Either

```
char result[2048] = "";
```

in the caller, or

```
result[0] = '\0';
```

at the top of readlist().

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help. If I change the while loop to just strcat(result, buffer); it returns the contents of entire file fine.